# Loop through all files with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib

I'm still beginner with Python and I need little help.There is a code that calculates Value at Risk for me.
In the main function there are three tasks where I need to put filename:

```
df = pd.read_excel("data/WTS.xls")
AllVaR.to_excel("portfolio/WTS.xls")
plt.savefig('charts/WTS.png')
```

Now I have to do it for 250stocks for my academic research.
I have all data files in folder "data" and I'm wondering how to create a loop for each file and how to put these filenames into pandas read,write and matplotlib function.

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir('data/'):
    df = pd.read_excel("data/filename?.xls")
    AllVaR.to_excel("portfolio/filename?.xls")
    plt.savefig('charts/filename?.png'
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: do you want them in individual dataframes or in combined?

Comment: I need individual, every stock in separate chart and output xls file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glob` and `os`:

```
import glob
import os
for f in glob.glob("data/filename*.xls"): 
     base = os.path.basename(f)
     basewoe = os.path.splitext(base)[0]

     df = pd.read_excel(f)
     AllVaR.to_excel("portfolio/"+ base)
     plt.savefig("charts/"+ basewoe +".png")
```

Comment: In this situation i put f like this?

df = pd.read_excel("data/f.xls")
AllVaR.to_excel("portfolio/f.xls")
plt.savefig('charts/f.png'

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work for me. I've posted current code first question.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Is there any error thrown? "Process finished with exit code 0" usually means that everything is fine and the process completed without errors.

Comment: I said it because this loop didn't work for me. This reading excel file and saving excel output and figure  was working without loop. But now nothing happened. There is no excel output and figure. Maybe there is something wrong with directories. I have main folder "Python" with var.py and folders data, portfolio, charts inside "Python" folder. The data folder contains 250 stocks ticker.xls

Comment: If your files are called "ticker01.xls", "ticker02.xls" etc. you of course need to adapt the glob statement to `glob.glob("data/ticker*.xls")`.

Comment: oh :) my files are called  for example, TSLA.xls, AAPL.xls. In this case I should just use glob.glob("data/*.xls") ?